# Are co-routine callbacks thread-safe?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

## Context:

*Unity Co-routines are not multi-threaded according to this [Article](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/208707516-Why-should-I-use-Threads-instead-of-Coroutines-). Therefore, if coroutine callbacks are accessing a global variable, I would assume there will not be thread conflicts.*

## Example:

```
//Declaration
private IEnumerator Resolve(WWW request, Action<WWW> callback)
{
    while (!request.isDone)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    callback(request);
}

//Invocation - called constantly
StartCoroutine(Resolve(request, request => {GlobalVar = request.text;}));
```

*Can someone who has experienced this confirm that coroutines are indeed synchronous or `GlobalVar` is Thread-Safe?*

Comment: Everything that is synchronous is by definition thread-safe, you can't have thread conflicts with only 1 thread.

Comment: Check the -Game Logic- section on https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/monobehaviour_flowchart.svg . Coroutines and yields have a specific time they are called in Game Loops [the Game loop is always a single thread. I know of no exception to that]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had an argument in the comments with someone about this recently.

<s>I can't find those comments now, but...</s> [Found it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61794/discussion-on-answer-by-philipp-unity-coroutine-vs-threads).

## No, coroutines are [not threads](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15499/coroutine-confusion.html?childToView=15501#answer-15501) and cannot encounter a race condition

Comment: I don't know that "race conditions" are not possible.  Certainly if there is an interleaving call to yield, the state of the shared data could change.  It may be more accurate to say that with co-routines in Unity are cooperative multitasking and therefore have no preemption.  Most of the issues in multitasking still apply - certainly reentrancy, deadlocks, and TOCTOU conditions.

Comment: @Mitch I tested it every way I could think of. The data never got modified on an unexpected order. I'd be happy to try out some alternatives, though.

Comment: Consider two calls that both access a shared state, change it, then restore it to the former state.  `doWork(); var prevBackgroundColor = this.BackgroundColor; this.BackgroundColor = Colors.Red; doWork(); yield(); this.BackgroundColor = prevBackgroundColor;`.  `BackgroundColor` can get stuck red due to the shared state captured in `prevBackgroundColor`.

Comment: @Mitch The coroutine with shorter time remaining will do its task first. If both have the same amount of time remaining, then the one that was invoked first will run first. There is no race possible here, as the invocations are from a single thread, therefore one of them *must* be called first in a deterministic fashion.

Comment: The race is whether the entire block of code runs before it is run again.  This could be because `doWork()` calls `A()` or due to two calls being interleaved by the scheduler.  Synchronization is still needed to avoid the shared `BackgroundColor` from getting stuck red.  (The same pitfalls occur with `async`/`await` even though it is single-threaded.)

Comment: `whether the entire block of code runs before it is run again` "If it runs before it runs? What? I did not understand that.

Comment: `StartCoRoutine(A()); StartCoRoutine(A());` - assuming `doWork()` takes time to complete, the code prior to yield will run twice before the first invocation finishes.

Comment: @Mitch Ok, I see. Yes. I will agree that that would occur.